# What is the correct way of using GMP integer functions in C programs?

Tags: c, arrays, biginteger, gmp

I'm trying to calculate the index of Fibonacci number with 1000 digits.

```
int i = 0, cnt = 2;

mpz_t limit;
mpz_init (limit);
mpz_ui_pow_ui(limit,10UL,999UL);

mpz_t fib[3];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    mpz_init2(fib[i], 1024UL);

mpz_set_ui(fib[0],1UL);
mpz_set_ui(fib[2],1UL);
```

**I think there's something wrong with assigning 1 to 1st and last element.** I know that because those elements are not changing.  But the loop should be valid till cnt becomes 4782.

> The condition in while loop is only satisfied `2` times `if`.. `<=0` or `3` times `if` .. `>=0`.

```
while(mpz_cmp(fib[i],limit)<=0) // should be <= only, not >=
    {
    i=(i+1)%3;
    cnt++;
    mpz_add(fib[i],fib[(i+1)%3],fib[(i+2)%3]);   
    }

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    mpz_clear(fib[i]);

mpz_clear(limit);

printf("Fibonacci number with more than 1000 digits: %d\n",cnt);
```

Please help find the logical error in this (it is compiling perfectly).

P.S. I don't want to use in-built mpz_fib_ui.
[Integer Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Functions.html#Integer-Functions)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Thanks for suggesting that, but even after editing the code, it still doesn't seem to give the answer.10^999 is correctly stored in the limit variable.

Comment: GMP can do in-place addition (`mpz_add(a, a, b)`), so you only need two values. You could use, for example, `i = 1 - i` to toggle between the two, or you could get rid of `i` altogether and use `cnt % 2`, or `cnt & 1`. (Make `cnt` unsigned for a possible slight efficiency boost, not that it will be noticeable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the for loop, i=3, so the conditional statement for the while loop depends on fib[3]

Adding i=0; before the while loop fixes it, and gives me the desired output:

Fibonacci number with more than 1000 digits: 4782

Comment: Thanks, that is so stupid of me. From next time, I'lll keep an eye on the value of each variable.